# React FontAwesome Icon not passing props for onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, font-awesome

I have a react web application and I have installed and imported FontAwesome icon library.

https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome

```
 import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
 import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
 import { faIgloo } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
 import { faStar } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

 library.add(faStar);
```

I am unable to get the props from the object when onClick is called.

It looks like when I click around the icon I am triggering my react button and the props are being passed fine. If i click directly on the icon, the onClick is triggered but the props are not passed.

```
<button  key={item.title} value={item.title} onClick={this.updateFavourites}>
<FontAwesomeIcon size="3x" icon="star" />                                
</button>


updateFavourites = event => {

    console.log("IN UPDATE FAVOURITES" + event.target.value);
    this.setState({
        selectedFavourite: event.target.value    
      });


      if (this.state.favourites.includes(event.target.value)){
        // Find and remove item from an array
        var i = this.state.favourites.indexOf(event.target.value);
        if(i !== -1) {
            this.state.favourites.splice(i, 1);
        }  
      }
      else{
        this.state.favourites.push(event.target.value);   
      }
}
```

What am i doing wrong? I have read every post related to this issue that I could find.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `<FontAwesomeIcon size="3x" icon="star" />` does not have any value. Keep in mind that you are using event.target.value in `updateFavourites` method, the icon will be the "target" when you click directly to it.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I now understand that I was trying to get props from the icon, which does not have the same props as a button.

Comment: If this helps you, accepting my answer is always appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by passing the updateFavourites function the value as an argument instead of trying to get the value from the object through props.

Changes are below.

updateFavourites function:

```
 updateFavourites = event => {

    console.log("IN UPDATE FAVOURITES" + event);
    this.setState({
        selectedFavourite: event 
      });


      if (this.state.favourites.includes(event)){
        // Find and remove item from an array
        var i = this.state.favourites.indexOf(event);
        if(i !== -1) {
            this.state.favourites.splice(i, 1);
        }  
      }
      else{
        this.state.favourites.push(event);   
      }
}
```

Button / icon :

```
 <button  key={item.title} value={item.title} onClick={() => this.updateFavourites(item.title)}>
 <FontAwesomeIcon size="3x" icon="star" />                                
 </button>
```